# Import cufflinks : cannot import name 'plot' from 'plotly.plotly'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I tried to import cufflinks, with this code :

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot
import cufflinks
cufflinks.go_offline()
cufflinks.set_config_file(world_readable=True, theme='pearl', offline=True)
```

but it returns an error like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4cccab8ca8ac> in <module>
      5 import plotly.graph_objs as go
      6 from plotly.offline import iplot
----> 7 import cufflinks
      8 cufflinks.go_offline()
      9 cufflinks.set_config_file(world_readable=True, theme='pearl', offline=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\__init__.py in <module>
     17 
     18 from .plotlytools import *
---> 19 from plotly.plotly import plot
     20 from .colors import cnames, get_colorscale
     21 from .utils import pp

ImportError: cannot import name 'plot' from 'plotly.plotly' (C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\__init__.py)
```

At first, it was an error at `import plotly.plotly as py` code that said the plotly was deprecated, and recommend me to use `chart_studio.plotly`.
So, I change the code and it works, but the `import cufflinks` is still error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Fyi, I use jupyter notebook

Comment: This must be a bug that just started bc of the plotly reconfig.Hoping the plotly team or cufflinks developers can fix this asap. All it takes is changing cufflinks set up to reflect the new structure of plotly

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/issues/185) is from an opened issue from cufflinks source code page. Basically, your Jupyter Notebook is throwing an error because the source code hasn't been updated even after installing `chart_studio`.

To fix this problem, go to the directory that contains cufflinks source code. In your case it would be `\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cufflinks`. Within that directory, locate three files, namely: `_init_.py`, `plotlytools.py`, and `tools.py`. In each of the respective files, change "plotly.plotly" to "chart_studio.plotly" and save the file. 
Try running the import again.

This [post](https://community.plot.ly/t/cufflinks-after-plotly-4-0/26587) from plotly community might be helpful as well! Do note that this post actually redirects you to the original opened issue.

If you're familiar with Github PRs, [these are](https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/pull/198/commits) the proposed commits (hasn't been merged yet though..)